# log4j not showing info on the console

Tags: log4j

I'm new to log4j and trying to use it in a project. For some reason the info won't get displayed on the console. It only works when i change it to logger.error(). This is only happening in the userServiceImpl class the other classes like Controllers are fine.
This is the log4j.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration debug="false"
    xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
    <!-- This default ConsoleAppender is used to log all NON perf4j messages 
        to System.out -->
    <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss} %5p %c{1} - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <!-- The root logger sends all log statements EXCEPT those sent to the perf4j 
        logger to System.out. -->
    <root>
        <level value="ERROR" />
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
    </root>
    <logger name="com.click.heal.controller" additivity="false" >
      <level value="INFO" />
      <appender-ref ref="console"/>
   </logger>
    <logger name="com.click.heal.service" additivity="true" >
      <level value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="console"/>
    </logger>
</log4j:configuration>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your root category is at ERROR level.  Anything that doesn't fall under one of your other two loggers will fall under root, and will only log at ERROR level.  If you change your root level to INFO, I bet it logs, right?  Not saying that's what you want, but it would be a clue that your UserServiceImpl class is logging under root right now.

*EDIT*

Try turning additivity to false on your logger for the service package.  additivity means the messages propogate to the parent, and since the parent is root and root logs to the same console appender, it seems likely that this is causing the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that the class that I'm having problem is within the service package which is cover by the second logger in the log4j.xml.  I even changed the root level to INFO it's still not working. After I tried logger.getRootLogger().setLever(level.INFO) it start working. Looks like the root setup in log4j.xml is not working on this class